# Why this linear system doesn't have base points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I see somewhere that linear system of a non-negative degree divisor over a rational curve doesn't have base points, but I didn't understand why.

I don't understand what the degree has to do with base points.

**Remark:** I'm working over a curve, so my definition of a divisor is a sum $n_1P_1\ldots n_kP_k$, where $P_i$'s are points and $n_i$'s are integers.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

A smooth projective rational curve is just $\mathbb{P}^1$. A nonnegative divisor of degree $d$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$ corresponds to a section of the sheaf $\mathcal{O}(d)$. For $d > 0$, this sheaf has global sections spanned by $x^iy^j$ where $i+j = d$. For a point $P = [a :b]$, it's easy to see that there is *some* section that doesn't vanish at $P$: if $a$ is (without loss of generality) nonzero, one such section is $x^d$. So $P$ isn't a basepoint of $\mathcal{O}(d)$, making it base-point free.

**In other words:** Any two points $P$ and $Q$ are linearly equivalent on $\mathbb{P}^1$ (because you can find a rational function whose divisor is $P - Q$). So any two divisors of degree $d$ are linearly equivalent. Any divisor of degree $d > 0$ is linearly equivalent to $dP$ where $P$ is any point in $\mathbb{P}^1$. These are all in the same linear system and they have no points in common. Hence the complete linear system of all divisors of degree $d$ is base-point free when $d > 0$

Comment: I'm sorry but my background is just Fulton's algebraic curves. I don't know what is a sheaf yet.

Comment: What's your definition of a base point?

Comment: It's a point which belongs to every divisor of the linear system of the divisor. In another words, let's $S$ be a linear system, $P$ is a base point of $S$ if for every divisor $D\subset S$ we have $P\in D$.

Comment: I edited my answer to be more elementary. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. I didn't understand why the fact of any two points being linearly equivalent on $\mathbb P^1$ implies every divisor of the same degree are linearly equivalent. I'm so sorry, I really have troubles with this subject.

Comment: Because then $\sum m_iP_i$ is linearly equivalent to $\sum m_i P = d P$ where $d = \sum m_i$ is the degree.

Comment: Why can you find a rational function whose divisor is P−Q? In another words, why can you always find a rational function such that $ord_Pf=1$ and $ord_Qf=-1$? Thank you very much again!

Comment: Suppose we have $P = [a :b]$ and $Q = [c : d]$. The rational function $\displaystyle \frac{bx - ay}{dx - cy}$ has divisor $P - Q$.

Comment: One last question, why the divisors with degree $d\gt 0$ doesn't have a point in common? this seems reasonable for me, but I can't prove this formally.

Comment: Take for example two distinct points $P_1$ and $P_2$. We have $P_1\sim P_2$, but $P_1\neq P_2$, which proves the assertion. Am I write?

Comment: @user42912 Be careful. This is not true on every algebraic curve! For instance, if $X$ is an elliptic curve then $P_1 \sim P_2 \implies P_1 = P_2$. The proof of this is by Riemann-Roch. If $P_1 \sim P_2$ then $P_1 - P_2 = div(f)$ for some $f \in K(X)$. Then $P_2 + div(f) = P_1 \geq 0$ which means that $f \in \mathcal{L}(P_2)$. However by Riemann-Roch, $\dim \mathcal{L}(P_2) = 1$ and $\mathcal{L}(P_2)$ certainly contains the constants, so that $f$ is constant and so $P_1 = P_2$.

Comment: @BenLim Thank you for your remarks. Notice that I' assuming that $P_1\neq P_2$ since the beginning.